# Linux RS485 communication only in one way

Tags: linux, serial-communication, rs485

I'm facing an odd issue testing serial communication between two linux machines. Both these machines have a serial RS485 port. I connected them with a cable and try to communicate. I implemented a small program to initialize the serial ports and I run this before start to communicate. To test communication I open 2 terminal on each machine: the first is used to echo-ing messages and the other to print the incoming messages with cat. The problem is: when I send messages from machine 1 I see them in machine 2, but when I send messages from machine 2, nothing happens on machine 1:

WORKING CASE

Machine 1:

```
echo test > /dev/ttyS0
```

Machine 2:

```
cat /dev/ttyS3
test
test
test
...
```

---

NON WORKING CASE

Machine 2:

```
echo test > /dev/ttyS3
```

Machine 1:

```
cat /dev/ttyS0
```

How is it possible?

Comment: Maybe there's a misconfig in your ports and one is capable of handling it while the other can't? Is the output of `stty -F /dev/ttyX` consistent with what you expect?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The output of stty is the same for both ports, but what worries me are all that undef...:


speed 9600 baud; line = 0;
intr = <undef>; quit = <undef>; erase = <undef>; kill = <undef>; eof = <undef>; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>;
start = <undef>; stop = <undef>; susp = <undef>; rprnt = <undef>; werase = <undef>; lnext = <undef>; flush = <undef>;
min = 1; time = 0;
-brkint -icrnl -imaxbel
-opost -onlcr
-isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echoctl -echoke

Comment: those are special characters, that's just a way for Linux to know you want it to send the interrupt signal when some key (or combination of keys) is pressed, as far as I know that should be a problem at all, even on my working RS232 adapter I have some undef values

Comment: Probably is some cabling problem. Are you sure they are RS-485?